# Discussion about the necessity of syntax highlight

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, formatting

As far as I have noticed, the site does not have any syntax highlighting capability.

The following annotation [does not work](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/how-to-convert-this-arduino-code-snippet-to-avr-gcc/10965#10965):

```
<!-- language: c-->
```

and the programming language tags do not add syntax highlight either.

As a significant part of the questions include some kind of code snippet, I think it would be a useful feature on this site as well. In my opinion, it would slightly improve the question quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does seem to be rather a lot of code here...

Ok, this is enabled. Note that there are currently *no defaults*, so you'll need to use the hints to trigger highlighting; moderators can also specify a default language (including the "default" that works for most C-like or XML-like languages) for any tag.

Comment: Thanks Shog9♦, that's much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have just switched the "Code Language (used for syntax highlighting)" option on the [ros](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ros) tag from `<none>` to `default`, so syntax highlighting is now activated on the question mentioned.

I have just gone through all tags with more than 5 questions, picked out tags which I think might benefit from a code language being set, and updated them as follows:

- `default`: [algorithm](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) [arduino](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) [computer-vision](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) [pid](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pid) [software](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)
- `lang-c`: [c](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) [robotc](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robotc)
- `lang-cpp`: [c++](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- `lang-matlab`: [matlab](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)
- `lang-py`: [python](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)

Any suggestions for changes to other tags would be more than welcome.

## See [Suggestions for changes to the code language of tags](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1334/37).