# Suggestions for changes to the code language of tags

Tags: discussion

[Thanks to Shog9♦](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1332/37) we have had *Code Language (used for syntax highlighting)* enabled on *Robotics*.

I have gone through all tags with more than 5 questions, picked out tags which I think might benefit from a code language being set, and [updated them](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1333/37), but I have almost certainly missed tags which might benefit from being changed from `<none>` to either `default` (which apparently works for most C-like or XML-like languages) or a more specific option (for example `lang-c`, `lang-matlab` or `lang-py` etc).

If you have a suggestion for other tags which might benefit from having their *Code Language* changed, please add an answer on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [opencv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opencv) would benefit from a C++ syntax highlight. Though, most of the time this tag is accompanied with [computervision](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computervision), [ros](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ros) or [c++](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Comment: That's interesting, [tag:opencv] is already set to `default`. I must have changed it and forgot to add it to my initial list of changes. I think that `default` is probably better than `lang-cpp` at this point, as I can see someone wanting to include `xml` in an [tag:opencv] question, and `default` would syntax highlight both code and configuration.

Comment: Yes, default is a better choice then.

Comment: @MarkBooth On this [question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/672/pid-line-follow-with-three-sensors-in-not-exactly-c/678#678) syntax is also enabled. Is it because of the [tag:programming-languages] ?

Comment: It includes the [tag:algorithm] tag.

Comment: Oh, yes I missed that one.